# Composite function $g \circ f$ is injective prove that $f$ is injective

Tags: functions

Just want to ask if I've done this question correctly

Let $f: x \to y$ and $g: y \to z$ be functions. Suppose that the composite function $g \circ f$ is injective. Prove carefully that $f$ is injective.

Answer: $f(x) = y(x)$ for some $x,y \in X$, then $g(f(x)) = g(y(x))$, i.e.
$g \circ f(x) = g \circ f(y)$, so since $g \circ f$ is injective we have $x=y$, so $f$ is injective.

Is this correct?

Comment: Please pick up [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553)

Answer (score 1):

Your argument seems fine.

Just minor typo, suppose

$f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x,y \in X$.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate that.